# How to avoid "list index out of range" in BeautifulSoup (Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-2.x

When executing this code, I always get the error message: "IndexError: list index out of range". What can I do to avoid this?

```
import urllib
thisurl = "http://www.tutti.ch/stgallen/fahrzeuge/autos"
handle = urllib.urlopen(thisurl)
html_gunk = handle.read()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_gunk, 'html.parser')

for first in soup.find_all("li", class_="li-in"):
    #print first.select("em.fl.in-date")
    if (first.select("em.fl.in-date")[0].text is not None):
        time = first.select("em.fl.in-date")[0].text
        if (len(time) > 0):
            if first.select("em.fl.in-date")[0].text[6] == "H":
                zeit = first.select("em.fl.in-date")[0].text[11:16]
            print zeit
            if first.select("em.fl.in-date")[0].text[6] == "G":
                zeit = first.select("em.fl.in-date")[0].text[13:18]
                print zeit
```

Comment: What is a first (`seq[0]`) element of empty list?

Comment: Don't do the same select twice, store it as a variable and use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a check to see if list is empty or not. Try this

```
import urllib
thisurl = "http://www.tutti.ch/stgallen/fahrzeuge/autos"
handle = urllib.urlopen(thisurl)
html_gunk = handle.read()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_gunk, 'html.parser')

for first in soup.find_all("li", class_="li-in"):
    #print first.select("em.fl.in-date")
    if first.select("em.fl.in-date") is not None and len(first.select("em.fl.in-date")) > 0:
        if (first.select("em.fl.in-date")[0].text is not None):
            time = first.select("em.fl.in-date")[0].text
            if (len(time) > 0):
                if first.select("em.fl.in-date")[0].text[6] == "H":
                    zeit = first.select("em.fl.in-date")[0].text[11:16]
                print zeit
                if first.select("em.fl.in-date")[0].text[6] == "G":
                    zeit = first.select("em.fl.in-date")[0].text[13:18]
                    print zeit
```